# Find outlook mail after clicking todo flag as done

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, to-do

## The situation

Over time I flagged several mails as 'todo' without any date. When I want to do something, I can go to this list and pick an item.

However, this time I accidentally clicked on the wrong flag (thus marking it as done).

Now it 'dissapears' and is surprisingly hard to find,

## What did I try?

I did not succeed in finding it using any kind of search or sort of mails.

I also found some solutions for tasks (you can find those in the task list), but those do not appear to work for mails flagged as todo.

## The question

**How to find a mail of which you just clicked the todo flag?**

Answer (score 8):

I was able to click on the Task button on the bottom left corner (below Mail, Calendar, and Contact buttons). It brought up a view showing all of my current tasks but there was also an option bar across the top that allowed me to select viewing Completed tasks. When I clicked the Completed button, it showed the completed tasks, which I could then send back to my to-do list.

Comment: This worked for me - I had accidentally clicked the wrong item and "lost" an important TODO item.  Using the Task view and switching to "Completed" tasks allowed me to move it back to "to-do".  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Neither answer above worked for me. I was able to find the mail by doing the following:

1. IN the outlook menu ribbon, find the 'quick steps' box that contains the 'done' button.
2. click the down arrow at bottom to open the quick steps box
3. click on 'manage quick steps'
4. Select the 'done' button.
5. The 'done' settings will show you the folder where the emails are going.
6. You can edit the settings to change the folder where the 'done' emails will go also from this menu.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Go to Search Tab in Email View

Type in Search Bar: followupflag:completed

Absurd that this is so hard to find.

Answer (score 0):

Though I do not know of a way to search for them (would also be welcome), these mails can be found as follows:

1. Go to the Calender
2. Choose a layout with sufficient detail (Day, Work week, Week)
3. Look at the task section, for me it is shown below the actual calender

This task section also contains mails flagged as done, even though they do not appear to show up in the regular task list.

Of course the mail can now be flagged again to make sure it returns to your todo list.

Answer (score 0):

The To-Do List has a choise on the ribbon to select viewing just the completed items.

[Show mails marked completed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kS6jx.png)

Comment: This repeats what Ryan already answered on Jan 6 2017, but does help having a more visual explanation :) thanks